# How can copy one column data of one table1 into other table2 column and other clumns table2 empty?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my problem.I have two tables `Stdd` and `result`.

`stdd` columns:

```
id
fname
lname
gender
phonenum
city
```

`result` columns:

```
physics
chem
math
english
urdu
bio
total
id
```

I want that in `result` table the column `id` copy data from `stdd` column `id`, and other columns of `result` columns remain empty or null.

How can i do this please help. I try this but nor works for me

```
       update result set  id= (select id from stdd)
```

following error come

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>              Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when  the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery
>   is used as an expression.
>              The statement has been terminated.

I want this kind of output.Here is 'result' table [image: link]

I'm using microsoft sql server 2008

Comment: Does it must be an Update or could it be an Insert, too?

Answer (score 1):

You could use INSERT with a SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO result (id) SELECT id FROM stdd
```

With this your SQL Server adds per row in `stdd` one row in `result` with the id from `stdd`.

If you can use multiple columns, too.

```
INSERT INTO result (id, col2, col3) SELECT id, s_col2, s_col3 FROM stdd
```